# override annotation with CodeModel Java API

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

**How i can add `@Override` annotation to my method using codeModel?**

```
JMethod update = classe.method(JMod.PUBLIC, void.class,"update");
update.annotate(?);
```

i didn't find the `@Override` Class.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do, but `@Override` should be defined in `java.lang.Override`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I annotate override annotation on an overridden method using code model.

```
JMethod update = classe.method(JMod.PUBLIC, void.class,"update");
update .annotate(jCodeModel.ref(Override.class));
```

PS: : a late reply, may help other who find the same problem.